# How to update a csv from another csv considering a combination of columns as the primary key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am having a block in my assignment to build a python project to do the following task. I'm kindly seeking help from you to make it complete!
I have 2 CSVs with same headers, which are:

`[ID,Date,time,type,status,member,account,property,credit quantity, debitquantity, Net quantity, credit value, debit value, Net value, currency]`

One csv is input.csv which contains input values for a run and other csv is system.csv which act like a database containing all the summed up values after each run. system.csv must be updated based on the input.csv.

When updating the `systems.csv` the following combination of fields is considered as the primary key: `'Date', 'member', 'account', 'property'`

if the values of the primary key is found in the systems.csv each values under credit quantity, debit quantity, Net quantity, credit value, debit value, Net value must be added to the existing values as follows:

**input.csv**

```
ID,Date,time,type,status,member,account,property,credit quantity, debit quantity, Net quantity, credit value, debit value, Net value, currency
id01,2023.03.16,21:00:00,visa,active,xyz,acc001,cc,100, 0, 1000, 100, 0, 1000, usd
id02,2023.03.16,22:00:00,visa,active,abc,acc002,cc,0,200, 2000, 0, 200, 2000, usd
```

**system.csv**

```
id101,2023.03.16,08:00:00,visa,active,xyz,acc001,cc,500, 0, 5000, 400, 0, 4000, usd
id102,2023.03.16,09:00:00,visa,active,abc,acc002,cc,0,600, 6000, 0, 200, 2000, usd
```

**system.csv after run**

```
id101,2023.03.16,21:00:00,visa,active,xyz,acc001,cc,600, 0, 6000, 500, 0, 5000, usd
id102,2023.03.16,22:00:00,visa,active,abc,acc002,cc,0,800, 8000, 0, 400, 4000, usd
```

Currently I've taken two csvs as dataframes and trying to do the process. but since my lack of knowledge please help me to complete this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why the `input.csv` and `system.csv` have differents ids. In the former, you have `id01` while in the latter, you have `id101`. Is it a typo ? Can you *double-check* ?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use :

```
df_in = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
df_sys = pd.read_csv("system.csv") #with optional `header=None, names=df_in.columns`


pkeys = ["Date", "member", "account", "property"]
scols = df_in.select_dtypes("object").columns.difference(pkeys)
ncols = df_in.columns.difference(scols.union(pkeys))

df_run = (
    pd.concat([df_in, df_sys])
        .groupby(pkeys,  as_index=False, sort=False).agg(
            {**{col: "sum" for col in ncols},
             **{col: "first" for col in scols}})
        [df_in.columns]
)

# df_run.to_csv("system.csv", index=False) #uncomment to overwrite the old `.csv`
```

Output (`system.csv` *in a tabular format*) :

| ID | Date | time | type | status | member | account | property | credit quantity | debit quantity | Net quantity | credit value | debit value | Net value | currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id101 | 2023.03.16 | 21:00:00 | visa | active | xyz | acc001 | cc | 600 | 0 | 6000 | 500 | 0 | 5000 | usd |
| id102 | 2023.03.16 | 22:00:00 | visa | active | abc | acc002 | cc | 0 | 800 | 8000 | 0 | 400 | 4000 | usd |

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the response. I tried this code. but instead of updating system.csv get cleared! Is it possible to happen because of my mistake or can i modify the code to get it work?

Comment: You're welcome but what do you mean by *"..position csv"* ? Can you show a screenshot of the problem and/or update your question to clarify the expected output/behaviour ?

Comment: sorry fot the mistake I edited my comment

Comment: Do you mean by get cleared that you got an empty `.csv` ? If so, this can't be possible with the given examples.

Comment: when I print the df_run this is what it show,
```Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID, Date, time, type, status, member, account, property, credit quantity, debit quantity,  Net quantity,  credit value,  debit value,  Net value,  currency]
Index: []```

Comment: It means that the given examples does not match your actual data design.

Comment: would you please suggest an approach to execute?

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you because most likely your inputs/examples does not match your actual data and/or you missed a detail when describing your problem. As you can see, if you run my code with your two given examples of `.csv`, you'll have a valid (*non empty*) `df_run`.